# Excel: Too many arguments

Tags: excel-2010

My intense equation is below, ultimately trying to merge 20+ cells into one cell based on how the copy came over from Word:

```
=IF(H18662=TRUE,(Q18662&CHAR(10)&IF(H18663<>TRUE,Q18663&IF(H18664<>TRUE,
Q18664&IF(H18665<>TRUE, Q18665&IFH18666<>TRUE, Q18666&IF(H18667<>TRUE, 
Q18667&IF(H18668<>TRUE, Q18668&IF(H18669<>TRUE, Q18669&IF(H18670<>TRUE, 
Q18670&IF(H18671<>TRUE, Q18671&IF(H18672<>TRUE, Q18672&IF(H18673<>TRUE, 
Q18673&IF(H18674<>TRUE, Q18674&IF(H18675<>TRUE, Q18675&IF(H18676<>TRUE, 
Q18676&IF(H18677<>TRUE, Q18677&IF(H18678<>TRUE, Q18678&IF(H18679<>TRUE, 
Q18679&IF(H18680<>TRUE, Q18680&IF(H18681<>TRUE, Q18681&IF(H18682<>TRUE, 
Q18682&IF(H18683<>TRUE, Q18683&IF(H18684<>TRUE, Q18684&IF(H18685<>TRUE, 
Q18685&IF(H18686<>TRUE, Q18686&IF(H18687<>TRUE, Q18687&IF(H18688<>TRUE,
Q18688&IF(H18689<>TRUE, Q18689&IF(H18690<>TRUE, Q18690&IF(H18691<>TRUE, 
Q18691&IF(H18692<>TRUE, Q18692&IF(H18693<>TRUE, Q18693&IF(H18694<>TRUE, 
Q18694&IF(H18695<>TRUE, Q18695&IF(H18696<>TRUE, Q18696&IF(H18697<>TRUE, 
Q18697&IF(H18698<>TRUE, Q18698&IF(H18699<>TRUE, Q18699,""),""),""),""),"")
,""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),"")
,""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),""),"")),"")
```

Comment: You're missing a `(` before H18666

Comment: Also, instead of doing a bunch of ands of IFs of something not equal TRUE you can use DeMorgan and NOT the OR of all of them, note that OR accepts a range or several cells.

Comment: in a salutation like this you could copy and paste the excel function into something like notepad++ and use newline/indenting to make it easier to read and pick up errors

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, you can't nest more than 6 `IF()` calls inside another `IF()` call. So I don't think there is a workaround to make this work in a single cell formula